# Are function prototypes needed in header files?

Tags: c, function, header

I am programming in robotc which is just c programming with add-ins (follows all c rules). In order to organize my code I have put my subroutines in header files and are referencing from my main c document. Can I still reference the methods in the header files from the c document without putting function prototypes in the 
headers?

For example:

Code in main1.c

```
    #include header1.h
    task main()
    {
      header_method();
    }
```

Code in header1.h (no function prototypes)

```
   header_method()
   {
   //do stuffs
   }
```

---

Or do I have to do this:

```
   void header_method();

   header_method()
   {
   //do stuffs
   }
```

The reason is that I can only declare a certain amount of global variables for my robot in robotc.

Comment: I don't see how the reason is relevant. A function prototype is not a "global variable"...

Comment: I think I worded it wrong. Robotc limits the amount of function prototypes I can use.

Comment: Why would [ROBOTC](http://www.robotc.net/) impose an arbitrary limit like that? Is it a restriction on the free trial download? If so, you might have to do something ugly to work around the limitations (or pay for the full version). Knowing exactly what the limits are would help.

Comment: Actually Keith, I have the full version. I believe the robotC wiki said that ROBOTC imposes the limit simply b/c the robot can't handle it. I don't remember the exact limits but it was 200 something global variables.

Comment: Function prototypes are not global variables.

Comment: Apparently the RobotC developer environment counts them as global variables. RobotC is mostly based of off C, but unfortunately there are some weird 'quirks' and 'exceptions'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should (almost) never put function *definitions* in header files, as you've done in your `header1.h`.

Header files should contain function *declarations* (prototypes).

(A "prototype" is a function declaration that specifies the types of the arguments. There are non-prototype function declarations that don't specify argument types, but they're obsolescent and there's no reason to use them.)

Function *definitions* (with the `{` ... `}` code that implements the function) should be in `.c` files.

Each `.c` file should have a `#include` directive for any functions that it calls *or defines*.

And each header file should be protected from multiple inclusion by [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

The idea is that each function *declaration* appears exactly once in each *translation unit* (each source file that you compile), and each function *definition* appears exactly once in your entire program.

If you have a function that's used in only one `.c` file, you can put its declaration and definition in the same `.c` file (and you should probably define it as `static`). In fact, if the definition appears before any calls, you can omit the separate declaration; the definition itself acts as a declaration.

(Functions defined as `inline` can complicate this model a bit; I suggest not worrying about that for now.)

Comment: so put function prototypes in header files? right? So i'm using the header as Abstract Interfaces like in OOP by declaring the functions, implementing them with #include and defining the methods actions within the main.c code.

Comment: @KiroYakuza: Yes, I believe that's what I said. More importantly, do *not* put function definitions in header files.

Comment: Inline link is broken - not enough chars to suggest