# How to divide C code in different files

Tags: c, header

I'm doing a code in C right now and the problem is that it's quite large. I've been doing some research about how to separate this code and the solution more attracting is to try and put some generic functions in a header file instead of putting them at the beginning of my .c code.

The problem comes when I read about this header files and I see that they are used to define MACROS. I started reading about it and what I see is strange definitions for me of variables (I mean strange because I normally don't define that kind of variables in a .c file).

Any thoughts on how to do this before I get my hands dirty?

Comment: This is a very well and widely discussed topic.  Look into compiling to object code and then linking multiple object files to produce an executable using a Makefile.

Comment: Thank you! @DavidHoelzer I'll continue looking into that then

Comment: Could you provide an example of one of these "strange" macros?

Comment: Basically after doing a little more reasearch I realized that what in my source of info was called a macro is just a chunk of code. I see that a header is basically a code that whenever you write #include "header.h" in your .c, will be there like if you wrote it in the .c code. Thanks for reading the post anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as I understand your problem, you are trying to make an header file for your project, am I right? If this is the case, perhaps you are referring to #ifndef, #endif etc. etc. These are commands that will be executed by the preprocessor. You should give it a read. When you have finished your header save it in .h extension. Furthermore, when including your header, this has to be in the same folder of the .c file and you have to include it like that :

```
#include "myHeader.h"
```

In the header you just have to write down the prototype for your function. Then create a .c file myHeader.c and do the actual function. Remember to include you header in both of your .c files.

To compile it use the following :

```
gcc -c myFile.c -o myFile.o
gcc -c myHeader.c -o myHeader.o
```

Then you have to link the objects and you are done :

```
gcc myFile.o myHeader.o -o filename
```

Comment: You say that I write a prototype in the header(myHeader.h) and then do the function I just prototyped in (myHeader.c) file in order to use it in myFile.c. Two questions arise, whats the difference between the "prototype myHeader.h and the code in myHeader.c and why can't I put everything in the header and simply say #include "myHeader.h" in the myFile.c program?? Thanks!!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180734/are-function-prototypes-needed-in-header-files and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/167723/what-should-and-what-shouldnt-be-in-a-header-file

Comment: If you have other questions, here I'm. Just ask ;)